# Angular 7.2 - ng new project command creates bunch of node_modules in my root directory

Tags: angular-cli

Recently I ran the `ng new MyApp` command to create a new `Angular 7.2` project. However, after creating the app there are a bunch of files installed in the root of the project which, I guess (not sure), should have been installed / added in the `node_modules` folder.

A month ago I also ran the `ng new app` command (`Angular 7.0`) and this worked fine. I already re-installed my Node.js (to v 10.15.1).

Any clue what is going wrong?

Some additional info below.

**The files installed in the root of the new project:**
[image]

**Warnings after running the ng new command:**
 [image]

[image]

**Angular cli version:**
[image]

Comment: Nothing in the folder where you ran the `ng new` command that may have caused this?

Comment: Already tried 2 different folders on 2 different drives, happened both times.

Comment: @Nicolas did you get its solution?

Comment: @VishalMittal Sadly not